# GridBagLayout doesn't fill all the space

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a panel which is used as a part of card layout. The panel uses `GridBagLayout`. I add two components to it: `JTextArea` with fill set to BOTH and `JTextField` with fill set to horizontal. They are only taking up the horizontal space.

```
        // Chat card setup
        JPanel chatCard = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gc.weightx = 2;
        chatArea = new JTextArea();
        chatCard.add(chatArea,gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        gc.weightx = 2;
        JTextField msgField = new JTextField();
        msgField.setActionCommand("SendText");
        msgField.addActionListener(listener);
        chatCard.add(msgField, gc);
```

It currently looks like this

[image: Panel with GridBagLayout]

Comment: What is your expected output? please share.

Comment: Well I thought the JTextArea would take up all the space and the TextField would be just a small bar(its size is ok) at the bottom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with `gc.weighty`

```
     ...
    gc.weightx = 2;
    gc.weighty=1;
    chatArea = new JTextArea();

    ...
    JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane(chatArea);
    chatCard.add(scrollPane,gc);
    ...

    ...
    gc.weightx = 2;
    gc.weighty=0;
    JTextField msgField = new JTextField();
    ...
```

**Add `JTextArea` in `JScrollPane` otherwise you will get an unexpected result when the rows are larger than its height.**

**use `gc.insets=new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);` if you want some space from top/left/bottom/right.**

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: I did. Interestingly your code gave not exactly what I needed. There was still some unused area. 

I set JTextArea weighty to 1 and the JTextFields to 0. It now seems to be okay.

Comment: yes you can change it. I just give you a hint. A hint is sufficient for an intelligent guy. :)

Comment: I did it before. But I removed thinking maybe it was the one causing problems. I will re-add it :)

Comment: congrats, you got my last vote of the day as I have now run out.

Comment: My pleasure. Good night and Thanks a lot. I am learning from you guys.

Answer (score 3):

@Braj has the answer for GridBagLayout -- use the weighty constraint, and 1+ to his answer, but I think that your set up would be much better if you used a BorderLayout, placed your JTextArea in a JScrollPane, placed the JScrollPane BorderLayout.CENTER and the JTextField BorderLayout.SOUTH (also known as BorderLayout.PAGE_END).

```
  JPanel chatCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
  int rows = 20;
  int cols = 40;
  JTextArea chatArea = new JTextArea(rows, cols);
  chatCard.add(new JScrollPane(chatArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);

  JTextField msgField = new JTextField(cols);
  msgField.setActionCommand("SendText");
  // msgField.addActionListener(listener);
  chatCard.add(msgField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Comment: You might actually be right... I got so carried away with using GridBagLayout today that I forgot about the more basic one

Comment: @Bebras: but again, braj answers your actual question correctly. 1+ to his answer.