# The layout makes the JFrame minimal and there is no content

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I want to make a `JFrame` containing two `JPanel`s thanks to a `Layout`. On the left is the result (despite the `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`) and on the right when I resize the frame:

[Screen of the result](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/755098201509071540ProblemJFrame.png)

Here is the minimalized code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * The Frame which will contain one or two Panels.
 *
 */
class Frame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel panAction;

    public void JFrame() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints info = new GridBagConstraints();
        info.gridx = info.gridy = 0;
        //info.gridwidth = 1;
        //info.gridheight = 2;
        info.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        //info.weightx = 1;
        //info.weighty = 1;
        JPanel buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel(this);
        add(buttonPanel, info);

        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        pack();
    }

    public void changeSecondPanel(JPanel panel) {
        if(this.panAction != null) {
            remove(this.panAction);
        }

        GridBagConstraints info = new GridBagConstraints();
        info.gridx = 0;
        info.gridy = 1;
        //info.gridwidth = 1;
        //info.gridheight = 2;
        //info.weightx = 1;
        //info.weighty = 1;
        info.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        add(panAction, info);
        this.panAction = panel;
    }
}

/**
 * The upper Panel.
 *
 */
class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ButtonPanel(final Frame frame) {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        JButton button = new JButton("CREATE");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.changeSecondPanel(
                        /**
                         * The bottom Panel.
                         */
                        new JPanel() {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    {
                        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}


public class PanelProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I tried `GridLayout` and `BorderLayout` but it didn't solve my problem. I already checked [Can components of a gridbaglayout fill parent frame upon resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723998/can-components-of-a-gridbaglayout-fill-parent-frame-upon-resize), [GridBagLayout doesn't fill all the space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047701/gridbaglayout-doesnt-fill-all-the-space) and many other sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `void` method named `JFrame` looks suspicious.

```
public void JFrame() { ... }
```

I think you intended to write a constructor like

```
public Frame() { ... }
```

The layout code that you wrote is not being called. This fix would solve that problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right, I did this mistake when I minimalized the example. The question is updated now and with the `add(button)`. It makes more sense now that it had a different behaviour from my bigger code.

Comment: @Qu'est-cet'yont: Tanmay has answered your original question correctly and succinctly (1+), and now you have a new problem. The proper StackOverflow etiquette is to both up-vote and accept Tanmay's answer, and then ask a **new** question on this site regarding your new problem. Please don't completely change the question now and invalidate Tanmay's efforts and help.

Comment: Sorry, I thought questions were to be usefull for other people. As this question has uninteresting mistakes (added when I simplified the code no to let this work for other people), I thought I had to correct it to make it logic. Not sure the -1 I received was relevant though as I made real efforts so that the question be confortable.

Comment: @Qu'est-cet'yont: the -1 was for invalidating all of Tanmay's work. Understand that he and all of us are volunteers, and that it's not really nice to have someone try to help you, only to invalidate his effort and help.

Comment: @Tanmay Patil Frame is reserver word for awt.Frame, that's the same as swing.JFrame, something like as MyFrame it could be ....

Comment: @Qu'est-cet'yont: Please feel free to create the new question and post its link here. Would be glad to help. Referring to http://sscce.org/ would be much appreciated.
@HovercraftFullOfEels: Thank you for reminding me the quality of this community, the very highest.
@mKorbel: The name of class in the original question is `Frame`. Although it's not a great idea, it's definitely not invalid. So I played along.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Yes, I know that `Frame`is a bad idea, but it was just to create a simplified code of what I did. Note that I didn't bother to up-vote immediately because the last time I tried, I was told I didn't have enough reputation for the mark to be counted.